# Ckeditor and uploading images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

In my project I use Ckeditor with Carrierwave. Everything seems to be fine, but I can't upload images. In my `config.js` file I have:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/ckeditor/attachment_files';
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/ckeditor/pictures';
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/ckeditor/attachment_files';
};
```

In `routes.rb` I have a route: `mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'`. When I try to upload an image, and send it to server, I get an error in server logs:

```
Started POST "/ckeditor/pictures?CKEditor=announcement_body&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-13 10:30:44 +0300
Processing by Ckeditor::PicturesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000006c4abe8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161013-4806-f9y5ss.jpg>, @original_filename="Kapsen HS205.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"Kapsen HS205.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "ckCsrfToken"=>"8gAsQ8c95ik1BcS474ERHnkMsn35H0efXOjkJ2EW", "CKEditor"=>"announcement_body", "CKEditorFuncNum"=>"1", "langCode"=>"en"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `process' for #<Class:0x00000006b83778>
Did you mean?  proc):
```

If I push `Ok` button, there is an alert message: `Image source URL is missing`.
What can be wrong with the code? What am I missing? Thanks ahead.

Comment: It's because CKEditor not uses the Carrierwave gem, It's inbuilt use the paperclip gem. You have to move your gem with the paperclip because both will not work same time.

Comment: The documentation tells, that Ckeditor uses Carrierwave.